# docker-compose changes permissions of ssh-agent

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ssh-agent

I have a Dockerfile which includes:

```
 RUN touch /ssh-agent
 RUN chmod 666 /ssh-agent
```

and a `docker-compose` file which includes:

```
    build:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ssh:
            - default
    restart: always
    user: "1001" 
    volumes:
        - type: bind
          source: /run/host-services/ssh-auth.sock
          target: /ssh-agent
```

The problem is that the permissions of `/ssh-agent` are changed to 755 inside of the container when I run it via docker-compose, which means I get a permission denied for the non-root user when trying to pull the repo (as it apparently requires the write permission).

When I log into the container as root, and change the permissions to 666, and log back as non-root, everything works.

When I run the container not using `docker-compose`, the permissions are preserved as 666.

Clearly the volume mount in docker compose changes these permissions, and as a rule the permissions on the host machine will be replicated onto the container. However:

1. The `/run/host-services/ssh-auth.sock` is what Docker calls a *magical volume* and as such it doesn't exist in your filesystem, so can´t look into its permissions.
2. I am apprehensive to change the permissions of `/run/host-services/ssh-auth.sock` not to mess with Docker settings on my host machine.

Any ideas?

Comment: bind mounts replace the file at the target entirely. the permissions of the file don't apply after mounting because the entire file is invisible after being mounted over by the new file